# How to get properties from an Object filtering by an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object like this:

```
const myObj = {
  '$prop1': 1,
  '$prop2': 2,
  '$prop3': 3
};
```

and an array of object like this:

```
const myArray = [
  {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop1'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop2'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop5'
  },
];
```

I am trying to write a function fo filter myObj and only get the fields I can find in myArray.propKey.

this is what I tried so far with no luck:

```
export const filterVariantContentByColumns = (myObj, myArray) => {
  const objArray = Object.keys(myObj).map(i => myObj[i]);
  return objArray.filter(value => myArray.includes(value.key_name));

  console.log(res);
};
```

any idea how to do that please?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the `myArray` into a Set of `propKey`s first, then filter `myObj` by whether the key being iterated over is in the Set:

```js
const myObj = {
  '$prop1': 1,
  '$prop2': 2,
  '$prop3': 3
};

const myArray = [
  {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop1'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop2'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop5'
  },
];
const haveKeys = new Set(myArray.map(({ propKey }) => propKey));
const output = Object.entries(myObj)
  .filter(([key]) => haveKeys.has(key))
console.log(output);
```

Comment: If you want the entries and not just the keys, then remove the final `.map` so that you have an array of entries. (if you need an object instead, you can use `Object.fromEntries` to turn the array of entries into an object)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and map found properties.

```js
const
    myObj = { $prop1: 1, $prop2: 2, $prop3: 3 },
    myArray = [{ prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop1' }, { prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop2' }, { prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop5' }],
    result = myArray.flatMap(({ propKey }) => propKey in myObj ? myObj[propKey] : []);

console.log(result);
```

With keys

```js
const
    myObj = { $prop1: 1, $prop2: 2, $prop3: 3 },
    myArray = [{ prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop1' }, { prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop2' }, { prop1: 'some stuff', prop2: 'some other stuff', propKey: '$prop5' }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(myArray.flatMap(({ propKey }) => propKey in myObj ? [[propKey, myObj[propKey]]] : []));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer.

```js
const myObj = {
  '$prop1': 1,
  '$prop2': 2,
  '$prop3': 3,
  '$prop4': 4
};
const myArray = [
  {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop1'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop2'
  },
        {
    prop1: 'some stuff',
    prop2: 'some other stuff',
    propKey: '$prop5'
  },
];

let propKeys = myArray.map(ele => ele.propKey)

let obj = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((ret, key) => {
  if (propKeys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
    ret[key] = myObj[key]
  }
  return ret
}, {})
console.log(obj)
```